# Peach tree leaves turning yellow

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, peaches

I have a Hale Haven peach tree that has leaves turning yellow and falling off. I live in Kansas and we just had so much rain. I have never seen this yellowing before this year. I also have rug laid around the tree to keep weeds out. I don't know what the problem is. It does have leaf curl which I am spraying for.If anyone can help me save this tree I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hi there, pictures really help with a diagnosis.  What kind of soil do you have? How old is the tree?

Comment: Don't trees shed leaves and change colour this time of year anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Same experience here in MS, incredible amounts of rain.  I would think the rug adds to the problem by holding the water. You may want to consider pulling the rug back during these rainy periods to allow it to dry a little quicker.  Also, if the ground around the tree is depressed or does not drain well, that can add to the problem.  I raised my young trees up off the ground a few inches by mounding them and that seemed to help a great deal.  Too much water can certainly injure or even kill a peach or plum tree, I've had several to die before I figured this out.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Fruit trees need drainage because water in humid climates isn't an issue.
But yellowing is often a symptom of not enough water. Poke your soil and if it's very dank and wet you're overwatering. If it's fairly dry to the touch, it needs more water. yellowing is also caused by fungal agents. One such "Taphrina Deformans" a fungus that causes leaf curl.
Zinc/iron deficiency is also a pre-cursor for yellowing. Add a fruit tree fertilizer